# How to configure vsftpd to send me an email on user login process?

Tags: pam, vsftpd

I want to send a mail to abc@abcd.com when someone is logging in via FTP. I have tried using /etc/pam.d/vsftpd "session optional pam_exec.so /path/to/my/emailing_script.sh" but it doesn't work (i have tested this script in /etc/pam.d/sshd and it works).

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for vsftp to use the pam sessions you need to enable it in the configuration file:

add (or update) the line

```
session_support=YES
```

without that line PAM sessions will not be used so your PAM session module will not be run either.

Look for "session_support" on [this documentation page](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, i have checked if pam_service_name is vsftpd and it was but it doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of sending an email you could write something on disk. If that works then there is a problem with the emailing script.

Comment: I have tested my emailing script with /etc/pam.d/sshd and it works. There is no problem with it. Right now I'm strace-ing the vsftpd process and trying to figure it out how it uses pam.d.

Comment: it looks like it will not create sessions unless activated in the conf file (see updated answer).